# MongoDB, php - find all docs that do not match array of $text searches

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb

1. MongoDB (`Title` - is text index):

sample data:

```
{_id: 1, Title: 'Some title'}
{_id: 2, Title: 'Some word'}
{_id: 3, Title: 'Some bad word'}
{_id: 4, Title: 'No stop word'}
{_id: 5, Title: 'No more title'}
{_id: 6, Title: 'Some stop'}
```

2. Array of MongoDB `$text` search request's:

sample data:

```
[
'some -bad',
'word -bad',
'good -bad',
'"some word" -bad',
]
```

Need to find all `MongoDB` docs which don't match any of this `$text` search from array.

Trouble in case of big data.

The approach i take to solve:

- find all `_id's` for first search,
- then for 2nd, etc..
- As result will get a huge array of `_id`'s (Example: `$not_matched_ids`).
- Then I need do something with this data and source DB. For example, delete all records from DB which in `$not_matched_ids`. But `$not_matched_ids` is huge array and DB is big.

MongoDB `$in` - isn't good solution. Is there another algorithm?